# Is it possible for 3 os in one machine?

Tags: linux

Currently on my machine there were multiple os like windows and ubuntu16.04. Now i want to install kali linux on machine. is it possible for 3 os in one machine. my machine consist od 1 tb,  4 gb ram..

Comment: why not? [How to install 145 operating systems on one PC](https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/how-to-install-145-operating-systems-on-one-pc-264235/) http://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?147959-How-to-install-and-boot-145-operating-systems-in-a-PC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have 3 operating systems on one machine.

Since you already have Windows and Ubuntu dual boot, you probably have grub boot menu, where you choose between ubuntu and windows, if you install Kali, you should just get another entry in boot menu.

There is always possibility that something will go wrong, and that grub gets corrupt during Kali install, and if you want to be sure that your current dual boot will not get messed up, you can install Kali inside a virtual machine on either Ubuntu or Windows.

You can download VMware Player, or Virtualbox or some other free virtualization software and install Kali inside it, if you don't want to experiment with 3 OS boot.

You can also see here about triple boot Ubuntu/Win7/Kali question.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/437836/triple-boot-win7-ubuntu-kali

Answer (score 2):

If you have a boot manager, you can have any number of operating systems.  The most i have had at once is 26.  You just need to install them and boot them in a way that the OS will boot.  Some boot managers will hide partitions, etc.  Some will load quite happily off an extended disk on a second partition.

Microsoft windows 10 and some earlier versions, even support booting iso files.  Whether this will be passed to the OS, is a different matter.